# How to extract an URL segment in React

Tags: reactjs

I have inherited a project and are very new to React.

The problem is that I don't know how to extract an URL segment like `123456` from the URL `page/123456`.

Here is some code for I sidebar I want to use the URL segment in. I kept it short so it is as clear as possible where I want the URL segment.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        URL segment: 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default compose(withRouter))(Sidebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a router configured properly then you might be able to find that value as a string in the `this.props.match.params`. You can take a look to the [following example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)(please note that it's using react hooks and the main difference for you would be to use `this.props.match.params` instead of useParams()).

P.S. you should call withRouter instead of passing it to the compose method. E.g. `withRouter(Sidebar)` and if you want to use it with connect I guess you can just call one inside the other: `connect(...)(withRouter(Sidebar))`